# Force HTTP to HTTPS Redirect in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, https

Hi currently i bought SSL Certificates from Godaddy and install in on LoadBalancer. I have an zend framework app, but i have the issues with site redirection to Https. Following are my Bootstrap code that i found easiest way to redirect my site to https :

```
 protected function _initForceSSL() {
     if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443') {
      header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
      exit();
    }
```

Unfortunately server error is return. What am i missing here? Thanks

Update:

.htaccess at root of file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: these type of redirects has to be done in .htaccess and not in your application code

Comment: many answers here - http://serverfault.com/a/116209/79206

Comment: i tried few on .htaccess but still no effects, i update my question above to include my .htaccess.

Comment: @emaillenin for my case where index.php are inside public folder? I am using Zend Framework

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->isSecure()` should be used to check for secure transport.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Zend Framework, you could try with the following code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: this error is returned "This webpage has a redirect loop" what might the cause be..?

Comment: @zlippr can you post your entire htaccess file in the question?

Comment: The above are my entire htaccess file content, also there is htaccess within the public folder with same content.

Comment: @zlippr remove the htacess file inside the public folder. there should be only one htaccess at the **root of the application**

Comment: still not resolve. I remove htaccess from public folder and replace the above code in my root htaccess but i have this message "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: http://www.raterz.my if you access by https://www.raterz.my (https) it will works as secure site

Comment: I am not getting redirect loop. If I goto http, it works as http. If I goto https, it works as https. HTTP to HTTPS redirection not happening - have u changed yoursite.com to raterz.my in your htaccess?

Comment: Yes that is of cause need to change, currently it works if users access by https manually of if they click a link. But i upload the above code, it does redirect to https://www.raterz.my (secure) but still shows up redirect loop message.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this function to your Bootstrap file:

```
protected function _initForceSSL() {
    if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443') {
        header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me.

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule .* index.php
```